# Calling TransactWriteItems or BatchWriteItems API without calling GET items first

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I would like to update items in DynamoDB table. I only want to update 2 properties within each item.
If the item doesn't already exist, I want to ignore it.
I tried both TransactWriteItems or BatchWriteItems APIs, but with them I have to call getItems api first to filter out items that do not exist.
Is there a way to avoid calling getItems api call?

index.js

```
const {DocumentClient} = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");
const documentClient = new DocumentClient({region:'us-west-2'});
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const filteredItems = await client.getItems(event.body.items)
  await client.updateItems(filteredItems, event.body.soldPrice, documentClient);
}
```

client.js

```
const updateItems = async(filteredItems, soldPrice, documentClient) => {
   let params = {
      RequestItems: {
        [tableName] : {
           filteredItems.map((key) =>({
              PutRequest: {
                Item: {
                  itemNumber: key.itemNumber,
                  soldPrice: soldPrice,
                  lastModified: new Date().toISOString()
                }
              }
           })
        }
   };
   documentClient.batchWrite(params).promise()
}
```

UPDATE:
I also tried following and this wiped out the existing values:

```
const buildUpdateRequest = (filteredItems, soldPrice) => {
  return items.map((item) => ({
    PutRequest: {
        Item: {
            'itemNumber': item,
            'soldPrice': soldPrice,
            'lastModified': new Date().toISOString()
        },
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(itemNumber)'
    }
  }));
}
const batchWriteInvoices = (filteredItems, state, documentClient) => {
  const params = {
    RequestItems: {
        [tableName]: buildUpdateRequest(filteredItems, state),
    }
  };

  documentClient.batchWrite(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html).

In cli it would looks something like the following for a PutItem. The same logic applies to your BatchWrite or TxWrite.

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --item file://item.json \
    --condition-expression "attribute_exists(Id)"
```

Comment: I just did that and it overwrote the existing values in DynamoDB. I will update the original question with code that was doing this

Comment: That's expected, PutItem is an overwrite operation. If you want existing values to remain then you need to use UpdateItem. BatchWriteItem can't update batches, but TransactWrireItems can.